GET request error while getting profile info from LinkedIn API
We did try to GET LinkedIn API in EC2 and localhost and it works.
It doesn't work only in E2E! Here is the message from the E2E team -

Our suspicion is that the IP has been blacklisted on LinkedIn's end, as we are not seeing any issues with our infrastructure or network configuration. Please contact LinkedIn Customer Support regarding your IP being unable to access the API. From the output provided, we can see the connection being reset at 108.174.10.22, which is LinkedIn's IP. Please ping this IP and check whether it is reachable from the VM.

Can you please help us fix this issue. Thanks!
When we pinged the LinkedIn IP from E2E VM we are getting an error.
Can you please whitelist the following IPs -
164.52.196.36    
172.16.126.52    
108.174.10.22   
108.174.10.22:443 
2406:69c0:1000::32 (IPv6)  
2406:69c0:1000::5d/36 (IPv6)  
2406:69c0:1000::1 (IPv6) 

This is the error we got -
errors: [
    Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 108.174.10.22:443
        at createConnectionError (node:net:1647:14)
        at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1706:38)
        at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
        at processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
      errno: -110,
      code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '108.174.10.22',
      port: 443
    },
    Error: connect ENETUNREACH 2620:109:c002::6cae:a16:443 - Local (:::0)
        at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1181:16)
        at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1711:5)
        at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
        at processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
      errno: -101,
      code: 'ENETUNREACH',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '2620:109:c002::6cae:a16',
      port: 443
    }
]


I'm facing very similar issue. Did you solved it?
